# Caculating % Change Measure in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, percentage, measure

I have a table with 3 fields: Date, Name, and Index Value. I am trying to create a measure which will calculate the % change in Index Value over a filtered period per Name.

So if when I create a chart and adjust the time period (date period) the measure will adjust the calculation to find the % change in index value over that time period.

Here is a screenshot of some example data (which matches my dataset):

[image]

And here is a the data as text:

Date,Name,Index Value
30/09/2022,Company A,100
01/10/2022,Company A,101
02/10/2022,Company A,103
03/10/2022,Company A,101
04/10/2022,Company A,100
05/10/2022,Company A,101
06/10/2022,Company A,103
07/10/2022,Company A,101
08/10/2022,Company A,102.5
09/10/2022,Company A,103
10/10/2022,Company A,103.5
30/09/2022,Company B,104
01/10/2022,Company B,104.5
02/10/2022,Company B,105
03/10/2022,Company B,105.5
04/10/2022,Company B,106
05/10/2022,Company B,106.5
06/10/2022,Company B,107
07/10/2022,Company B,107.5
08/10/2022,Company B,108
09/10/2022,Company B,108.5
10/10/2022,Company B,109

So in this example the measure would calculate the % change for Company A and Company B over any time period, but for example it could be between 30/09/2022 to 08/10/2022

I have tried to calculate a measure - here's the code (although it's incomplete but hopefully will give you an idea of where I was trying (and failing) to go)

```
    % Change = DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(Returns[Index]),filter(ALLSELECTED(Returns), 
Returns[Name] = earlier(Returns[Name]) && Returns[date] = 
MAX(Returns[date] , ))))
```

So what I am trying to do here is divide the index value at the maximum date associated with each Name in the dataset by the index value associated with the same name at the minimum date. This will give in effect an 'end value' and a 'start value' per name and the % change is simply end_value/start_value - 1.

Comment: Please post sample data as text.

Comment: Added as text - is it in the right format?